# How can we use Apache Pig for unformatted data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to use `Apache pig`, but until now I have just parsed formatted data like csv or comma separated etc.

But if I have some data separated by ';' & '@&@' etc, how can I work with it?

Like when I used **MapReduce** I split data by ";" in map and then again by "@&@" in reduce.

Also suppose for example we have a csv file with first field username which is made by "FirstnameLastname" format,

```
raw = LOAD 'log.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (username: chararray, site: chararray, viwes: int);
```

By above example we can just get whole username, but how can I get both Name and Lastname different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do just about anything Java or Python can do with UDFs in Pig. Pig is not intended to have an exhaustive set of processing functions, but just provide basic functionality. Piggybank fills the niche of custom code for doing stuff by collecting a bunch of community-contributed UDFs. Sometimes, piggybank just doesn't have what you need. It's a good thing UDFs are pretty simple to write.

- You could write a [custom loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html#load-store-functions) that handles the unique structure of your data at load time. The custom load function manipulates the data with Java code and outputs its structured columnar format that Pig is looking for. Another nice thing about customer loaders is you can specify the load schema so you don't have to write out the `AS (...)`

  ```
  A = LOAD 'log.csv' USING MyCustomLoader('whatever', 'parameters);
  ```
- You could write a [custom evaluation function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html#eval-functions). Sometimes a function like `SPLIT` or `TOKENIZE` just isn't good enough. Use [TextLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#textloader) to get your data in line-by-line, and then following up with a UDF to parse that line and output a tuple (which can then be flattened into columns).

  ```
  A = LOAD 'log.csv' USING TextLoader() as (line:char array);
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(CustomLineParser(line));
  ```

Comment: Thank you dude.I knew we can write custom loader , custom functions etc etc (like I used to do in mapreduce),But just wanted to make sure about is there any inbuilt method? And your answer was really helpful.

Comment: I tried TextLoader() , looked good.I do not have fixed format.Again thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [STRSPLIT](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/pig/piglatin_ref2.html#STRSPLIT) to split the string the second time:

Also `;` could be split by `\\u003B`

Comment: Thank you brettdj that will help me.Can you please send me reference link , I haven't got it any where.